# How to get routes by Grape API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-grape

I use gem, grape for api.
I tried to get api urls by the command `rake grape:routes`

```
    namespace :grape do
      desc "routes"
      task :routes => :environment do
        API::Root.routes.map { |route| puts "#{route} \n" }
      end
    end
```

but I got by `rake grape:routes`

```
    #<Grape::Router::Route:0x007f9040d13878>
    #<Grape::Router::Route:0x007f9040d13878>
    #<Grape::Router::Route:0x007f9040d13878>
    #<Grape::Router::Route:0x007f9040d13878>
    ...
```

I want something like this.

```
    version=v1, method=GET, path=/services(.:format)
    version=v1, method=GET, path=/services/:id(.:format)
    ...
```

My grape implementation is below. This works well.

```
    module API
      class Root < Grape::API
        version 'v1', using: :path
        format :json

        helpers Devise::Controllers::Helpers

        mount API::Admin::Services
      end
    end



    module API
      class Services < Grape::API
        resources :services do
          resource ':service_id' do
            ...
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try adding the the below to your *Rakefile* as discussed in this [*proposal*](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/issues/631)

```
desc "Print out routes"
task :routes => :environment do
  API::Root.routes.each do |route|
    info = route.instance_variable_get :@options
    description = "%-40s..." % info[:description][0..39]
    method = "%-7s" % info[:method]
    puts "#{description}  #{method}#{info[:path]}"
  end
end
```

*Or*

Try the below as mentioned [*here*](https://dukex.svbtle.com/rake-routes-command-on-grape-gem)

```
desc "API Routes"
task :routes do
  API::Root.routes.each do |api|
    method = api.request_method.ljust(10)
    path = api.path
    puts "#{method} #{path}"
  end
end
```

And run `rake routes`

Also there are couple of gems([*grape_on_rails_routes*](https://github.com/syedmusamah/grape_on_rails_routes) & [*grape-raketasks*](https://github.com/reprah/grape-raketasks)) which are built for this purpose. You might be interested to have a look at them.