# Grape add new endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape

I'm using Rails 6 with Grape as API. I'm pretty new in Grape and I'm trying to learn how to add new endpoint using Grape. The idea is to get Index endpoint which is nested in v1/users/index

Here is my structure:

```
app/
  controllers/
    api/
      root.rb           - API::Root
      v1/
        base.rb         - API::V1::Base
        users/
             base.rb    - API::V1::Users::Base
             index.rb   - API::V1::Users::Index
```

`api/root.rb`

```
module API
  class Root < Grape::API
    default_format :json
    prefix :api

    # exception handling
    include Rescuers

    # helpers
    helpers ::API::Helpers::ParamsHelper

    # core API modules
    mount V1::Base
  end
end
```

`api/v1/base.rb`:

```
module API
  module V1
    class Base < Root
      version 'v1', using: :path
      content_type :json, 'application/vnd.api+json'

      # mount resource modules
      mount V1::Users::Base
    end
  end
end
```

`api/v1/users/base.rb`:

```
module API
  module V1
    module Users
      class Base < Grape::API
        version 'v1', using: :path
        content_type :json, 'application/vnd.api+json'

        # mount resource modules
        mount Users::Index
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`api/v1/users/index.rb`:

```
module API
  module V1
    module Users
      class Index < Grape::API
        desc 'Test'

        get do
          head 200
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # API
  scope :api do
    mount API::Root, at: '/'
  end
end
```

I want to have this `index.rb` in my routes as `GET v1/users/index` but when I type `rake routes` I don't see it. This should not do anything, I want to understand what is the core requirements when it comes to creation endpoint with Grape.

Comment: `rake routes` is a rails rake task, that won't work with grape, you need something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44657601/5215927

Comment: I don't think that's the case - when I tap `rails routes` I still see `api_root  /api.  API::Root` which is also grape routes

Comment: yes, that's the "base" route for the api, but in order to retrieve the grape routes you need another script, maybe you can use this `https://github.com/syedmusamah/grape_on_rails_routes`

Comment: Isn't the purpose of Grape that you only have one mapping in `routes.rb` to the api, and then add extra routes in Grape

Comment: We have a very extensive API infrastructure and we use `grape_on_rails_routes` as @mr_sudaca suggested

Comment: I would recommend not to use mounts of Grape. If you want to split your endpoints, use native Ruby modules https://nesteryuk.info/2020/04/12/grape-include-is-still-better-for-code-splitting.html

Comment: @DmitriyNesteryuk that works fine for simple cases however mounting allows for a lot more configuration and also creates much DRYer mechanisms for redundant mechanisms like CRUD. [mount configuration](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#mount-configuration)